# Swift - NSDateFormater is not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am calling an API to get some data. API response returns date and time in `String` format but when I parse it into `NSDate` using `DateFormatter` it shows `nil` instead of date.String formate that I get from API is `2016-10-09T12:15:17.000Z`.

Here is my code.

```
let dateString = dataDict.objectForKey("schedule_date") as! String
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
print(dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString))
```

Comment: Change your date formatter to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Comment: can u share the sample date string you recieve from response?

Comment: 2016-10-09T12:15:17.000Z this is the actual string i am getting from response.

Comment: @NiravD's format should work Syed

Comment: @Mr.UB yes his format works just as i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your date formatter like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

```
let dateString = dataDict.objectForKey("schedule_date") as! String
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
print(dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString))
```

**Note:** `SSS` is here for `milliseconds`.

Answer (score 0):

nil only comes when the format of the date set in the date formatter is not according to the date string received. Check your date format for the value received.